# Meu Javascript dá syntax error no Chrome e Safari mas não dá erro no Firefox?

Tags: javascript, html

Estes são meus arquivos:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap-collapse.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap-tab.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.mCustomScrollbar.concat.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/custom.js"></script>
```

Estou com o seguinte problema:

No Mozilla Firefox funciona perfeitamente. Já no Chrome e no Safari não executam de jeito nenhum. Erro:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token > custom.js:401

Já ocorreu este problema com alguém?

Comment: Tem algum erro na consola?

Comment: Seja mais descritivo, que erro está ocorrendo ? No Console de debug do Chrome (f12) está aparecendo alguma mensagem ?

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token > custom.js:401
event.returnValue is deprecated. Please use the standard event.preventDefault() instead. jquery-1.9.1.js:3345

Comment: Dá para postar aqui o conteudo do `custom.js`? Hmmm aliás, parece bem grande. Pode dar uma olhada perto da linha 401?

Comment: E colocar o erro na pergunta, editando-a? Fica mais fácil para outras pessoas entenderem o problema.

Comment: no seu navegador, aperte Crtl+Shift+I e observe se aparece algum erro na aba Console. E Atualize sua pergunta com os erros que encontrar lá. Dizer o conteúdo do seu custom.js e o que você está querendo fazer serão bastante úteis para que nós consigamos te ajudar

Comment: Jefferson, óptimo! assim pode editar a pergunta e colocar uma resposta, ou apagar a pergunta :) Se tiver mais problemas há aqui muita gente a querer ajudar

Answer (score 4):

Achei o erro.

Na linha 401 do meu arquivo custom.js fiz uma condição com o operador lógico "Maior ou Igual" assim:

```
=>
```

o correto é assim:

```
>=
```

Mas achei estranho que no Firefox rodou normalmente.

Comment: O firefox é parecido com o javascript, ele roda as coisas que não eram pra ele rodar. é triste..

Comment: O firefox suporta um troço chamado [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/arrow_functions), previsto na próxima versão da linguagem (CoffeeScript já usa). Você deu azar de esbarrar nisso.

Comment: @bfavaretto vale notar que as arrow functions do ES6 não são idênticas à fat arrow do CS, por exemplo, atualmente a sintaxe do ES6 requer uma lista de parâmetros -- `(a,b) => {}` ou `a => {}` -- enquanto o CS não tem problemas em ocultar a lista de parâmetros. Isto foi discutido no [encontro do TC39 de setembro/2013](https://github.com/rwaldron/tc39-notes/blob/master/es6/2013-09/sept-17.md#41-arrow-functions) mas parece que a maioria dos membros deseja manter a lista de parâmetros obrigatória, embora não tenha havido consenso.